# React-table: keep first row always on top when ordering the rest

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-table

I am creating a table in react-table V7 and MUI. I would like to have a table where I can sort all the rows, except for the first one. I would always like that row to be the first row.

How can I achieve this? I have created a code sandbox as an example:

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-heisenberg-l25rob?file=/src/App.js)

[image]

Comment: When you are fetching data, is it possible to use some transform function to create a new array and push this item first and then the remaining items from the response

Comment: The sorting happens within the react-table sorting mechanism, so i would like to find something inside that library that alllows me to keep that row first.

Answer (score 0):

First push the first element to an array and then push the search results then to the array
Eg:

```
const animals = ['zebra','monkey','ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];
const search=[];

search.push(animals[0]);

animals.slice(1);
// search operation
search.push(...animals.slice(1).sort())
console.log(search)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm looking for something that works within the react-table sorting mechanism